# panic for multilevel returns

Tags: go

Is there a better way to return from long sequences of recursive function calls?
I currently panic with a marker value like this:

```
type exitNow int
...
panic(exitnow(0))
```

to return multiple levels at once. At the root function a call to recover does general error handling (turning panics into errors) and handles exitNow as a special case.

This works fine I just want to know if there is a better way.

I already use a bool return value for a related purpose but using another one for this would be a pain. (every call to every function would need an if statment)

If it helps any this is part of the implimentation of a recusive decent parser.

Comment: Ad parser - maybe you know, maybe you don't know and maybe you want to check [go yacc](http://golang.org/cmd/yacc/).

Comment: yacc yick :p I never liked such tools, its more fun to write parsers by hand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this approach myself in my parsers. I don't panic with an integer value though. I use the actual current error as the panic message. The top level call doing the `recover()` simply appends some file/line/column information and then returns it as a regular `error`.

This method, and just returning errors from all functions are the only ways to do this in Go. The panic approach is a great deal more effective for the parser case, as it makes the lexer rules considerably simpler to implement (and read) as there are no `if err != nil { return }` parts littered everywhere.

Comment: I wasn't very clear but I use this for my equivelent of the exit keyword as well as panicing with strings for error messages. I like your point about it being cleaner, but it still feels a little hacky

Comment: The classic ["Defer, Panic and Recover"](http://golang.org/doc/articles/defer_panic_recover.html) document actually promotes this style of error handling for writing parsers. So even if it feels hacky, it's just okay.

Comment: See also ["Error handling in Go"](http://blog.golang.org/2011/07/error-handling-and-go.html).